# Dyntopo and Symmetry not working together?

Tags: sculpting, mirror, dynamic-topology

I'm new to Blender and I'm following Blender Guru's Anvil tutorial. In the video [Blender Intermediate Tutorial - How to Sculpt Details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywSq0bSYLWI&list=PLcpbyAte3x6Y0skyLUZEUKOlqcsFmPpHT&index=7), when Andrew is sculpting, he uses Dyntopo and Symmetry and it works seamlessly.

When I use it, I can see Dyntopo is being applied on the other side of the axis, but not in the same way.[image: assymetric anvil]

Right side is where I sculpted, left side is the mirrored side.

When I go into Edit mode, I can confirm Dyntopo is being applied on both sides.

 Here are the settings I'm using:
[image: settings]

I'm using Blender 3.5 on MacOS Ventura 13.4 by the way.

The file:
[image]

Comment: Maybe make sure that the origin is centered, or in Object mode, right click > Set Origin > To Geometry? Or please share your file

Comment: I already did that, unfortunately. I edited the question to include the file now.

Comment: Weird because it works fine for me

Comment: Actually, I think it doesn't have anything to do with Dyntopo. I just tried without it and the same problem happens: The mirrored side appears way more dented than the sculpted side. Did you enable any specific setting? Which brush did you use?

Comment: I kept your settings and used the Draw brush

Comment: Draw brush works fine for me. Does it work for you when you use the Scrape or Flatten brushes?

Comment: the mesh is probably not really symmetrical, thus the difference, to fix that, go in Edit mode, select all and > Mesh > Symmetrize, in the Operator box choose -Y to +Y, and try again?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that since the mesh itself is not symmetric, because of the holes on the top of the anvil, and because a Displace modifier has been applied. I think for now my best option is to just do the sculpting details on both sides manually. Thanks for your time, though!

Comment: Yes but if the mesh is not symmetrical, it explains your problem